# SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 44382

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]

This error is getting while using HTTP GET method

Comment: Don't post picture. rather post the actual code with the error. Are you using emulator? If you're running the server locally and using the Android emulator, then your server endpoint should be 10.0.2.2:3306 instead of localhost:3306

Comment: Please make sure that you have internet permision inside android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`) on the device is only accessible to the device itself.

### Solution 1 (Android only)

You can reverse-proxy a `localhost` port to the Android device/emulator running `adb reverse` on the command prompt like so:

```
adb reverse tcp:5000 tcp:5000
```

### Solution 2

Use the machine's IP address where the DB is running. Also, the DB should be listening to the IP `0.0.0.0` to be accessible outside the `localhost`.

Supposing the DB machine's IP is `192.168.1.123` it's going to be something like:

```dart
Future db() async {
  print('@');
  final conn = await MySQLConnection.createConnection(
    host: '192.168.1.123',   // <- Here
    port: 3306,
    userName: 'root',
    password: '',
    databaseName: 'flutter', // optional
  );
  print('^');
}
```

Just take care because changing the DB to listen to `0.0.0.0` is a security risk as the DB is going to be accessible to the outside world.